# Javascript cookie to distinguish between the page hits/views?

Tags: javascript

Here's the thing, I have created a mobile web-app having 6 pages only  (main.html, venue.html, program.html... , aboutus.html). Ss you guys can see main.html is the main landing page. We also have native mobile apps for Blackberry and iPhone and these native apps use some of my pages in their widgets. Now the issue is I need to distinguish between the page views or hits in such a way so that I could get a clear idea about from where my page is being requested or viewed and then hide/show some stuff depending upon from where the page is being requested. One interesting thing, as mentioned above main.html is the main landing page of web-version so we never use this page in our native apps. So I need to create a cookie on main.html and wanna check that cookie value on each of 6 pages. By following this approach what I want to do is e.g.

Let us say: If I got a hit from native app for venue.html, then in this case I will not get any cookie value as this user has not visited the main.html and reverse of this if some user has used my web-app/version then he/she has to go through the main.html (user is forced by us to view the main.html page first then others).

So after exploring everything I need you guys help to: 1. How to create such kind of cookie in javascript on main.html? 2. how to check that cookie value on rest of pages to know from where that page is being accessed?

Note: I don't want to store any expiry date/time in cookie and in `setcookie` method I want to set some constant value instead asking user to set some dynamic stuff through some alert dialog.

Any code snippet will highly be appreciated

Comment: Why -1 ? May i have pleasure to know his/her name? and if possible share the reason for this gift.

Comment: (No my -1) Your logic is structurally unsound. URLs are designed to identify unique resources. If you're using one URL for two resources, depending on the previous resource shown, you violate that unique-ness. This _will_ breaks caches (no, not _might_, this _will_ break caches).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like you are doing any pre-processing on the serving side of the equation. Meaning all your pages are static pages, you might want to look into pre-processing your pages using ASP, PHP, Perl or whatever other programming your server allows. By doing so, you open up the option of tracking movement of the user within your application.

Comment: Right these are simple static web pages. we don't want to complex the things. Do you have any suggestion for this situation in particular?

Comment: You might want to look into pre-processing your pages using ASP, PHP, Perl or whatever other programming your server allows. By doing so, you open up the option of tracking movement of the user within your application.

The other way, of course, would be to read the cookie being set by main.html on all the other pages, if they arrive on those secondary pages without the cookie, simply forward them to main.html to have it set.